# Error in my Tableau calculated field for counting days

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate the number of days for a project based on the active_flag.
If the active flag is true, the number of days should be calculated from the end_day till today.
If the active flag is false, the number of days should be calculated from the end_day till the last observation date (ob_date).  Below is my attempt:

```
if active_flag = True then datediff('day',[end_date],TODAY()) 
elseif active_flag = False then datediff('day',[end_date], max([ob_date])) end
```

[image: calc window with errors]

I see the errors so I'm looking for suggestions on how to re-write this calc to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You often came across this error "Cannot Mix aggregate and Non-aggregate". This is because you have called `max(aggregate)` with *"End date"* (Non-Aggregate). LOD is helpful in handling situations like this. So the correct code is

```
if active_flag then datediff('day',[end_date],TODAY()) 
else datediff('day',[end_date], {max([ob_date])}) end
```

By scripting **curly braces** before the max calculation, we have forced the Tableau calculation engine to find Maximum of all values in column "Ob_date".

LOD can elevate our calculation capacity. If you are interested  [checkout this](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/2/introduction-level-detail-expressions-36655)